# How to access nested nodes in json using angular httpModule?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, httpclient

I wanted to access nested nodes in JSON. I am able to get the parent level but when I am trying to access nested/sub-records getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Please suggest a solution so, that I can get another ul-li for assigned_to as well with multiple records

db.json

```
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Male",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "male.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "01-01-1987",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "score": "Updated",
      "checked": false,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 54,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 20,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score":99,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Female",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "female.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "dob": "31-12-1987",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "checked": false,
      "score": "Updated"
    }
 ]
}
```

app.component.html

```
<table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="allNonTrades" (change)="selectAllClicked($event)">
          </th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>Impact</th>
          <th>Score</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of allUser | tableFilter: form.value | paginate: { id: 'listing_pagination', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: totalRecords }">
          <td><input *ngIf="!isEdit"  name="nontrades" [checked]="user.selected" (change)="changeTradesByCategory($event)" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxClicked()"></td>
          <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{user.dob}}</td>
          <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
          <td>
            <div [ngClass]="getClass(user)">{{user.score}}</div>
            <div>
              {{user.assigned_to}}
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button *ngIf="!isEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-sm ml-2" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

app.component.ts

```
getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      this.getApplicableCounts();
      this.allUser.forEach((row: any) => row.checked = false);      
    });
  }
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestUser();    
  }
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllUser() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/users");
  }
  
}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<div>
  {{user.assigned_to}}
</div>
```

you can define another ngFor and show whatever you like inside it:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let assignee of user.assigned_to">{{assignee.dl}} - {{assignee.co_score}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's showing [object object] and when I am doing {{assignee.dl}} it's showing error as property doesn't exist on type 'string'. here is the code for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3iaw11?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: in your question you showed assigned_to to be an array of objects, but in the stackblitz, assigned_to is a string, that is why the stack is not working properly

Comment: if you look at the json it is a nested node so, i wanted to show the details on click of each record along with the count of how many applicable n how many not applicable in each record. if you can help me with that would be really helpful. if you see stackblitz its' showing [object object]

Comment: the linked stackblitz doesnt work for me, it fails to load

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3iaw11?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, https://angular-ivy-3iaw11.stackblitz.io/ see that works?

Comment: what do you want to show from that object? see my forked version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qqhii?file=src/app/app.component.html - notice I also changed userObj.assigned_to to be an array

Comment: can you also please help me to get the count of how many applicable and not applicable under each node?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350436/how-can-i-get-the-count-of-specific-nested-node-in-json-using-typescript-in-angu

Comment: @KunalVijan sure, I've posted an answer there and updated the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{user.score | json}}` and see result. You did not provide interface to debug error.